# Can a backticked identifier have a backtick in it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, grammar, identifier

Is it possible to escape a SQL identifier in either MySQL or BigQuery or any other RDBMS that allows quoting of identifiers with the `` ` `` character? For example:

```
select 1 as `select`
```

Works, but then How would I add a literal backtick to it, or is that just not allowed?

```
select 1 as `sel\`ect`
```

Comment: Why would you have a backtick in there?

Comment: @RiggsFolly for a parsing grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use a doubled backtick, eg:

```
create table `my``table` (`my``id` int);
```

This is similar syntax for including quotes in text, eg `'O''Leary'`

---

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/354439/1) of

```sql
create table `my``table` (`my``id` int);
insert into `my``table` (`my``id`) values (1);
select * from `my``table`;
```

outputs:

| my`id |
| --- |
| 1 |

By the way, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) says any UTF-8 character (except `U+0000`) is allowed in a back tick quoted identifier.

Comment: out of curiosity, how would you even 'insert' a `U+000` sequence into the string? Does mysql allow unicode escape sequences entered directly into a backtick quoted identifier?